Accessing the log in page to Backpack for Laravel returns an Error 500
I'm running/accessing Backpack perfectly fine on my development machine (mySQL 8.1.0, Laravel 10.48.3, PHP 8.2.10), but after uploading it onto the production server (mySQL 8.0.35, Laravel 10.48.3, PHP 8.3.1), I receive an Error 500 when I move to the login page (https:/xxxx/admin/login.
The composer.json file lists backpack/crud ^6.7, backpack/permissionmanager ^7.0, backpack/pro ^2.0, backpack/generators ^4.0.
There are no errors posted in the apache2 or php-fpm logs.  No error information appears in the browser's dev tools.
The public side of the site - which is fuelled from the same database - is working perfectly.
What can I do to track down the cause of this problem?
Thanks/Tom

When deploying, make sure you updated your APP_URL in the .env file to match your production.
Run a php artisan basset:clear && php artisan basset:cache after deploying the code to refresh the assets.
If you already had the application live add added backpack, make sure to clear routes and cache too.
Cheers

Thanks for your input. Alas, the APP_URL was correct and the route and cache cleaning didn't solve the issue.

Try to check error logs at storage\logs\laravel.log

Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the Laravel log was clean/clear.
